# Minecraft LAN 1.9.2 not showing up. (Using direct connect does not work, disabling firewall does not work.)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

My girlfriend and I are trying to play Minecraft together on the same wireless connection. It should be very simple; open a single player game, pause then open it up to LAN. Then the other person would connect. However, the game does not show up entirely, and we have tried disabling the firewall to see if that was the problem, which had no affect on the issue, also using direct connect with our IPv4 address, as well as a combination of both. Nothing seems to make the game appear, even waiting for long amounts of time. The only software I think may tamper with the connection would be Hamachi, but we both have it powered off and closed. Is there a solution for this or should I just contact my provider?

Comment: Are you on the same wifi? Or do you have Wifi1 and Wifi2 or something like that, if so you both need to be on the same one

Comment: If nothing has availed yet, a last resort would be to just create a port forward, and use that. Or create a mini server, using the LAN address in the direct connect.

Comment: We have bothed changed up and installed a few different wireless adapters and we have multiple wifis under connect. Wifi1 Wifi2 Wifi3 ect but the wireless connections appear only within the one we are using. I'm sure remnants of previous software from previous wireless adapters would cause too much of an issue. And yes, I've considered port forwarding as a last resort and I see that I'll probably have to do that now.

Answer (score -1):

How did you connect your computers?

You need a router or a routing software. The easiest is to join the same wireless network. But you have to keep in mind, that in your routers website (fritz.box etc) communication between computers has to be allowed.

If you dont have a router, try making your own wireless network with software like MyPublicWiFi (http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/de/index.html) or Connectify. You can also connect your computer with LAN and create a wired network with Connectify but this is not a free function.

Hope it helped :)